# Merge lines from a text file into another text file at specific points

Tags: merge, notepad++, txt

I have two separate text files; **question.txt** and **answers.txt**.
I would like to pull in the answers from the answer file into the question file, as shown below

**BEFORE:**

Question file contents:

1. How many sides does a triangle have?

A. 1

B. 2

C. 3

D. 4

Answer:

2. How many sides does a square have?

A. 1

B. 2

C. 3

D. 4

Answer:

Answer file contents:

1. C.
2. D.

**AFTER:**

Question file:

1. How many sides does a triangle have?

A. 1

B. 2

C. 3

D. 4

Answer: C

2. How many sides does a square have?

A. 1

B. 2

C. 3

D. 4

Answer: D

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not a programming question as described in the [help] pages.

Comment: Can you just try answering it. The question requires programming knowledge.  The art of programming it to be able to translate real world problems into to code.

Comment: Have you read the pages I suggested to learn about how to write a question that is on-topic here? Please look at bullet 3 within [help/on-topic]. Its states *"you must have made a good faith attempt to solve it yourself"*.

Comment: I have been playing around with Regex options in Notepad++ but to no avail.
i am hopeful a solution lies within Notepad++ rather than Python but i just don't know.
I guess i could pull it all into Excel and use vlookup but there are 1500 questions in total.
If you can tell if it is possible without resorting to Python i will go away and research that